# Generating points inside each polygon based on colorful raster layers data with QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, point, geometry-generator

I have to automatically generate points inside each polygon based on colorful rasterlayers point density and/or color. Each polygon has to have 'X' number of points depending on its surface area, for example: 4 points in 1 hectare.

So the points has to locate in the densest and/or highest spot and there has to be spesific amount of points inside polygon depending on its area. Points cannot be right next to eachother too, so there has to be a minimum value between each point

**Sidenote:** colors in rasterlayer are representing each tree and its height but I dont yet know if point locations will be based on tree density or its height, this I'll test and decide later.

[image]

Comment: Try Saga's **Local Minima and Maxima**

Answer (score 2):

##### Solution: the principle

Create a multiple of random points per area (like 100 times more than you want), then get the raster value for each point. Then select top or bottom 1% of these points, based on the raster value. Like this, you have your desired number of random points per polygon, but concentrated in areas with certain raster values (largest or smallest raster value).

##### Implementation

1. To get 4 points per hectare, use [random points in polygons](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgisrandompointsinpolygons) and set `number of points for each feature` to data driven override with an expression like this: `area($geometry)/10000*4` (if layer units are in meters).
2. Create substantially more points than you want, like 100 times more, thus multiply the number of points above with this value.
3. Now for each of the selected points, get the value of the underlying raster pixel by creating a new attribute field `"raster_attribute"` with the expression `raster_value('raster',1,$geometry)` - replace `raster` with the name of your raster layer and `1` with the band number.
4. Based on the raster value, select a certain percentage (like 1%) of the random points created, namely the largest N% or the smallest N% and delete all others. You now are left with just 1% of the initial random points: those with the largest or smallest raster values.

   To do so, use select by expression with this expression and make adjustments in lines 3 (percents) and 8 (largest/smallest values) as well as the fieldname `raster_attribute`:

   ```
    with_variable(
         'percentage',
         5,  -- change pecent of total points to be selected
    array_contains( 
        array_slice( 
            array_sort(
                array_agg ("raster_attribute"),
                0 -- 1 for smallest, 0 for largest N% values
            ),  
            0, 
            round (array_length(array_agg ("raster_attribute"))/100*@percentage)-1
        ),
        "raster_attribute"
    ))
   ```